# Is there an independent version of Overworld Zero?

Tags: system-shock-2

System Shock 2 has an item that is a portable game system, and one of my favorite is [Overworld Zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Shock_2#Overworld_zero).  Does this game exist independently outside of System Shock 2?

ps: I spend so much time in game playing this my co-op buddies rush to grab all the game systems and trash them to prevent me from playing...

Comment: This is at least halfway a software recommendation, if not most of the way.